# mysqldump как вместо insert сделать update?

Tags: mysql

Использую для дампа базы данных на тестовом сервере утилиту mysqldump которая запускается по крону.

```
mysqldump --host=127.0.0.1 --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --no-create-info --user=root --password='root' stead > tead.sql
```

На продакшене для импорта использую:

```
mysql --user=root --password='root'  test < afostead.sql
```

Так же по крону запускается.

В файл дамп попадает примерно следующая информация.

```
INSERT INTO `im_gruppy` VALUES (100,'Бумага для оргтехники',1,'100.png',1);
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при insert  когда находит Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' импорт прекращается. И хотелось бы еще обновлять старые записи.

Подскажите как можно с помощью mysqldump и mysql делать update строк и если строки нет то insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример запроса, дальше разберетесь

```
INSERT INTO `table` (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name="A", age=19
```

mysqldump --host=127.0.0.1 --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --no-create-info --replace --user=root --password='root' stead > tead.sql

Comment: Перечитайте о чем речь идёт! Про эти запросы я и без вас знаю.

Comment: Делайте дамп с этими флагами
--insert-ignore     Insert rows with INSERT IGNORE.

--replace           Use REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое ))) mysqldump --host=127.0.0.1 --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --no-create-info --replace --user=root --password='root' stead > tead.sql. Да решение проблемы измените плз ответ я Вам ответ поставлю.